# ¿Debo eliminar preguntas que no obtienen ninguna respuesta?

Tags: discusión, eliminación-de-preguntas

Las preguntas están bien escritas y cumplen con los requisitos, sin embargo, no he obtenido ninguna respuesta, tan sólo algunos comentarios.
Las preguntas ya tienen tiempo y ya no necesito la respuesta, ¿debo eliminarlas?

Comment: Dejala, no la elimines. siempre hay gente que mira la seccion de preguntas sin respuestas y puede acabar solucionandose. Pero una duda: no estan todas tus preguntas ya resueltas?

Comment: Yo las dejaría, en algún momento tendras respuesta.

Comment: ¿A qué pregunta te refieres? Como dice @loisb, todas tus preguntas que puedo ver están marcadas solucionadas, a menos que ya eliminastes la pregunta en cuestión. De paso, te felicito por no olvidar de marcar las respuestas a tus preguntas como solucionadas.

Comment: ¡No las elimines :D! Considero que si encontraste alguna respuesta a esas preguntas sería genial que la agregaras, es muy problable que alguien más en el futuro se encuentre con un problema similar o igual al que tuviste y en ese momento le será de utilidad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. No lo hagas. En resumen:

1. Una pregunta, aún sin respuesta puede inspirar a otros usuarios a hacer otras preguntas interesantes.
2. No tener respuesta hoy, no significa que no puedas tener respuesta mañana, la semana que viene o el siguiente lustro.

---

Hay algo de las comunidades StackExchange (SE) que personalmente me costó mucho tiempo de entender pero que creo que es fundamental: Aunque tú seas la primera persona que se beneficia de una respuesta, la respuesta es para el mundo, no para ti.

Cuando escribes una pregunta en una comunidad SE es una pregunta que posiblemente más gente se haya hecho o se vaya a hacer en algún momento; cuando recibes una respuesta será una respuesta que alguien haya necesitado o vaya a necesitar en el futuro.

Por eso mismo, conserva la pregunta: Tal vez no hayas recibido respuesta cuando lo esperabas pero seguirá siendo una pregunta válida y en el futuro (lejano o cercano) tal vez alguien responda y esa respuesta le sea útil a alguien más. ¡Estas publicaciones quedan aquí para la posteridad! y pueden servir de inspiración a otros usuarios.

Answer (score 2):

Bien teniendo en cuenta que cumplen lo requisitos para ser una pregunta valida, creo que eso dependera solamente de usted, pues no creo que nadie tenga la potestad de obligarlo ha relizar la accion de borrado que se comenta.

*Aunque creo que una parte de SO borra cierto tipo de preguntas, pero no se si esto es asi como comento o que criterios usa para ello (tiempo de la misma, votos negativos, o cualquier otra cosa), como digo no lo se.*

Yo personalmente pienso que la deberia de dejar, algunos motivos:

- Quizas algun dia algun usuario la pueda contestar.
- Quizas algun dia alguien tenga ese mismo problema y si ha sido contestada pues ya contaria con la solucion, y de no tener respuesta (como ahora) es tiempo que se ahorraria al no tener que formular la misma pregunta, pudiendo hacer upvote o crear una recompensa para dar mas visibilidad a su pregunta.